# Chef Override Attributes in KITCHEN_YAML (default/attributes vs Chef env vs KITCHEN_YAML

Tags: test-kitchen

So here is my question - providing some context. We have a use case where we have an attribute - holding an array of values defined in Cookbook - `attributes/default.rb` file. The attribute is overridden in Chef environment file - this was done under `override_attributes`, this was moved to `default_attributes`. The move was done because we want to be able to **override** the value in KITCHEN_YAML.

We use `kitchen-oci` Ruby GEM to provision the Kitcehn VM. Overrides from the Chef environment (*including from the attribute in question*) are used in the Chef recipes.

In `KITCHEN_YAML` file, the override for the attribute is defined under `attributes` section.

Now, when converging the Kitchen VM, the following is observed.

- If the Chef environment values are defined under `default_attributes` then the **actual** value becomes *additive*. That is, the attribute has a value that is combination of array items defined in Cookbook `attributes/default.rb` file and `KITCHEN_YAML` file.
- If the Chef environment values are defined under `override_attributes` then the values in `KITCHEN_YAML` have no effect.

Is above (from first point) expected? What would be the ideal way to enable overriding the values in `KITCHEN_YAML` without having to make a copy of the Chef environment and then making adjustment in that.